# Java Puzzler- What is the reason?

Tags: java, string, compilation, program-entry-point, puzzle

I wrote following code.

```
class String { 

    private final java.lang.String s; 

    public String(java.lang.String s){ 
        this.s = s; 
    } 

    public java.lang.String toString(){ 
        return s; 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String s = new String("Hello world"); 
        System.out.println(s); 
    } 
}
```

When I execute it, get following error

```
The program compiled successfully, but main class was not found.
  Main class should contain method: public static void main (String[] args).
```

Why is it so?... though main method is defined why system is not reading/ recognizing it ?

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow! 2) `class String{`  Don't name your class after an existing J2SE class.  It is at the very least, confusing.  3) That class also seems to do nothing beyond what a plain J2SE based `String` could achieve.  What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Trying changing this class name to Stringg causes it to compile properly, so it must be something about reusing the String class name

Comment: If you ever write a program like that in real life, you deserve to be *spanked!!*  :-)

Comment: Also, is this an interesting puzzle (in which case go for it) or something you actually plan to use? If so please don't

Comment: Guys relax! I already mentioned  that It was a puzzler :) I knew it would not run properly but i didnt get the reason.

Comment: *Java Puzzler*, are you talking about [the book](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+Puzzler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:zh-TW:official&client=firefox-a)?

Comment: @HappyDev Then you should read it, it's amazing.

Comment: @johnchen902 yes I have alreay read it, I own a copy of it, anyways thnx for suggestion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Becuase you must use a `java.lang.String`, not your own. In your main method, the `String` you're using is actually the custom `String` that was defined, not a real `java.lang.String`.

Here is the code, clarified a bit:

```
class MyString { 

    private final String s; 

    public MyString(String s){ 
        this.s = s; 
    } 

    public String toString(){ 
        return s; 
    } 

    public static void main(MyString[] args) { // <--------- oh no!
        MyString s = new MyString("Hello world"); 
        System.out.println(s); 
    } 
}
```

So, the lesson that you can learn from this puzzle is: don't name your classes as other commonly used classes!

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it so?

Because the `String[]` you are using at the point is not a `java.lang.String[]`.  It is an array of the `String` class that you are defining here.  So your IDE (or whatever it is) correctly tells you that the `main` method as a valid entry point.

Lesson: don't use class names that are the same as the names of commonly used classes.  It makes your code very confusing.  In this case, so confusing that you have confused yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Because the signature of the main method must be

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
```

and not

```
public static void main(mypackage.String[] args) {
```

Usually, `java.lang` is implied. In this case, your personal `String` is used instead. Which is why you should **never** name your classes as those already in `java.lang`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your class is named `String`, like the `String` class of Java. That's really bad, you shouldn't do that.

Because of that, when you write the declaration of main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

`String []` doesn't refer to Java `String` class, but to **your own class**, so java can't find it.

If you want java to be able to find it, you would have to write :

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
```

But really, it's not what you want, find an other name for your class.